# How to create unique id in flutter to add in the database

Tags: database-design

How to create a unique id in Flutter to add to the database in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package named as a UUID (https://pub.dev/packages/uuid).

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

var uuid = Uuid();
```

You can create like below

```
// Generate a v1 (time-based) id
uuid.v1(); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a'

// Generate a v4 (random) id
uuid.v4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'

// Generate a v5 (namespace-name-sha1-based) id
uuid.v5(Uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, 'www.google.com'); // -> 'c74a196f-f19d-5ea9-bffd-a2742432fc9c'
```